# How do I highlight a row if one cell value is bigger than another?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy, pandas-groupby

For each row in the Data Frame I would like to check two cell values against each other and if the condition:

(`df['QTY'] > df['AUTO ORDER']`)

is evaluated to true I would like to actually highlight the entire row in any color.

I've tried so many things. none of them worked for me, Any help is much appreciated.

My entire script is as follows:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import math
from pathlib import Path

def evaluateOrder ():
    try:
        data_folder = Path("/Users/adam 25/Desktop/")
        import_file_path = data_folder / "BRANCHESREQUESTSREPORTS6.xlsx"
        read_file = pd.read_excel(import_file_path, header=17, skipfooter=1)

        export_file_path = data_folder / "TESTED.xlsx"

        read_file = read_file.fillna(' ', axis=1)  # resolved updating the missing column entries

        # drop unnecessary columns
        drop_unnecessary_columns(read_file)

        remove_new_lines(read_file)
        # join_columns(read_file)
        insert_new_columns(read_file)


        read_file.style.apply(highlight, axis=None)
        print(read_file.head())

        read_file.to_excel(export_file_path, sheet_name='Revised Order', na_rep='', float_format=None, columns=None, header=True, index=None, index_label=None, startrow=0, startcol=0, engine=None, merge_cells=True, encoding=None, inf_rep='inf', verbose=True, freeze_panes=None) 
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)


def drop_unnecessary_columns(df):
    # drop unnecessary columns from the data frame.
    for i in range(1,21):
        index = f'None.{i}'
        del df[index]
    df.dropna(how='all', axis=1, inplace = True)
    # df.drop(df.columns[df.columns.str.contains(' ',case = False)], axis = 1, inplace = True)

def format_header():
    return 0

def join_columns(df):
    df['Product'] = df[['Product', '']].agg(''.join, axis=1)

def remove_new_lines(df):
    for column in df:
        if column is not None:
            df.rename(columns={column: column.replace('\n',' ')}, inplace=True)
            column = column.replace('\n',' ')

def insert_new_columns(df):
    # insert the min column
    df.insert(2, 'MIN', 0)
    # insert the max column
    df.insert(2, 'MAX', 0)
    # insert the max column
    df.insert(2, 'RECOMMENDED', 0)
    # df['MIN'] = (df['AUTO ORDER'] * 0.5).apply(np.ceil)
    # df['MAX'] = (df['AUTO ORDER'] * 1.5).apply(np.ceil)

    # not_approved = df['QTY'] > 0 & df['AUTO ORDER'] == 0
    # approved = df['QTY'] > 0 & df['AUTO ORDER'] != 0 & df['QTY'] <= (df['AUTO ORDER'].apply(np.ceil))
    # df.loc[not_approved, 'RECOMMENDED'] = 0


def highlight(x):
    c1 = 'background-color: red'
    c2 = 'background-color: green'

    df1 = pd.DataFrame('', index=x.index, columns=x.columns)
    m = x['QTY'] > x['AUTO ORDER']
    df1['QTY'] = np.where(m, c1, c2)
    # df1 = df1.mask(m, c2)
    return df1

evaluateOrder()
```

My sample data is in [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Yuetu9g-3CnBCqxIQFR1D2DqMp-Jp5Ne/view?usp=sharing).

Comment: Only change condition from `m = x['Expiration Date'] < today` to `m = x['QTY'] > x['AUTO ORDER']`

Comment: That didn't work as well, believe me I've tried them all.

Comment: Please add your sample data and your code, without data and code hard find problem.

Comment: Done so. in the question body.

Comment: Change `read_file.to_excel(export_file_path, sheet_name='Revised Order', na_rep='', float_format=None, columns=None, header=True, index=None, index_label=None, startrow=0, startcol=0, engine=None, merge_cells=True, encoding=None, inf_rep='inf', verbose=True, freeze_panes=None) ` to `read_file.style.apply(highlight, axis=None).to_excel(export_file_path, sheet_name='Revised Order', na_rep='', float_format=None, columns=None, header=True, index=None, index_label=None, startrow=0, startcol=0, engine=None, merge_cells=True, encoding=None, inf_rep='inf', verbose=True, freeze_panes=None) `

Comment: Yeah, such a dumb mistake I did there. Again thanks for being nice and helpful.